# How to concatenate all columns row-wise in oracle ignoring 4k char limit

Tags: python, oracle

I am concatenating all columns with applying NVL() function to each column.

I am using python to connect to oracle db so I am able to get the column names easily and then applying some join with the list get the desired select query like :

```
select NVL(col1,'?')||NVL(col2,'?')...
```

It was working fine until the aggregated value crossed 4k characters.

I tried to search and found about listagg but the problem with that is it is being used vertically and I want to concatenate rowwise.

This concatenated value I am using to generate an MD5.

Comment: Once you have it as a LOB (see other answers), review the cx_Oracle sample [return_lobs_as_strings.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/main/samples/return_lobs_as_strings.py) for the fastest and easiest way to fetch LOBs in cx_Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate them as a CLOB. To do that, either start with `EMPTY_CLOB()`:

```
SELECT EMPTY_CLOB()||NVL(col1,'?')||NVL(col2,'?')...
```

or use `TO_CLOB` on everything:

```
SELECT TO_CLOB(NVL(col1,'?'))||TO_CLOB(NVL(col2,'?'))...
```

or just `TO_CLOB` on the first column:

```
SELECT TO_CLOB(NVL(col1,'?'))||NVL(col2,'?')...
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d59779a3d55d1813f106ab6081458ae0)*

Comment: using this my database is making me disconnect

Comment: @EXODIA It works [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d59779a3d55d1813f106ab6081458ae0). If you have non-string columns then use `NVL(TO_CHAR(col1),'?')`

Comment: I tried to do TO_CLOB on all columns, but now I am getting - Buffer too small for CLOB to CHAR or BLOB_TO_RAW conversion

Comment: @EXODIA Your question does not mention anything about `RAW`s. This answers the question you asked; if you have more follow on questions then you can always ask another question.

Comment: In the end I mentioned that I am passing the concatenated value to generate MD5. For that sys.dbms_obfuscation_toolkit.md5(INPUT => UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(CONCATENATED_VALUE)

Comment: @EXODIA [`UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_raw.htm#ARPLS71383) takes a `VARCHAR2` input; it does not take a `CLOB` input. Since a `VARCHAR2` cannot have more than 4000 bytes asking how to ignore the 4k limit on something that has a 4k limit on its input seems to be a pointless task.

Comment: So i wont be able to create md5 of the generated clob ?

Comment: You will be able to generate a MD5 hash of up to 4k of data .... you can hash the long columns and then concatenate the resulting hashes or some other similar technique and then put that back in for a second round of hashing but `UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW` will not accept a `CLOB`. Or you can look for ways of doing it with a `LOB` such as [`DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_crypto.htm#ARPLS65700).

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting that long string into something, right? A variable? At Oracle's SQL level, it is limited to `VARCHAR2(4000)`, but in PL/SQL it becomes `32K` so - one option is to switch to PL/SQL.

Otherwise, use `CLOB` datatype instead of `VARCHAR2`.

---

Unrelated to what you're doing, but - `NVL` function is to be used to get some value in case of `COL1` is `NULL`. What you're doing is useless, as you're "converting" possible `NULL` value in `COL1` into an empty string (two consecutive single quotes, `''`) which is - in Oracle - equivalent to `NULL` so you could've just

```
select col1 || col2 || ...
```

It would make sense if it were e.g.

```
select nvl(col1, 'x') || nvl(col2, 'x') || ...
```

Comment: I got your point about '' and NULL. thanks

I am not storing that in variable. Direct running the query in oracle through python
Can you show an example to use CLOB ?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know Python.